# Pass array values to PostgreSQL from JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, stored-functions

I try pass integer array value a plpgsql stored procedure from JPA/Hibernate enviroment. But I always get an execpetion: *function fn_test_array(bytea) does not exist.*

I wrote a short demo application, which demonstrates the problem.
(Wildfly AS, JPA/Hibernate, PostgreSQL 12)

*Yes, I know, the int[].class is a rubbish, but then what is the solution? :)*

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_test_array(in_arr integer[], OUT res_int bigint)
RETURNS bigint
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN

res_int := 201;
 
END;
$function$
;
```

Call from java:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query2 = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("fn_test_array")
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("in_arr", int[].class, ParameterMode.IN)
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("res_int", Long.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
.setParameter("in_arr", new int[]{1, 2});

query2.execute();
Long res2 = (Long) query2.getOutputParameterValue("res_int");
System.out.println("res2: " + res2);
```

Exception:

```
11:26:11,933 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-19) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
11:26:11,933 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-19) ERROR: function fn_test_array(bytea) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 15
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: so you can pass it as a string of values concatenated with "comma or pipe" and split the value as an array in postgres function/procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I not found sophistical solution. However, I soled it with JDBC connection. It works like this.

```
final Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);  //Hibernate session
session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            String query = "{CALL fn_test_array(?, ?)}";
            CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall(query);
            
            Integer[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 5};
            final Array in_arr = connection.createArrayOf("integer", numbers);            
            stmt.setArray(1, in_arr);            
            stmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.BIGINT);
            stmt.execute();

            Long resLong = stmt.getLong(2);
            System.out.println("resLong: " + resLong);
            stmt.close();            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How about using JpaRepository method please?